# Completing tasks from many queues sequentially

Tags: php, redis, queue

I have PHP + Redis as queue.

I have three queues:

1. Create client (Queue name = 'create_client').
2. Create task for client (Queue name = 'create_task').
3. Send created task to client (Queue name = 'send_task').

I can send tasks to this queues independently. For example, I have client and I want to create task for him. I put task into queue 'create_task', and well done.

But I have next issue:

I want to do all three tasks successively.
First I want to create client, after creating I want to create task for him and after that, I want to send task to him.

Question: How I may do this.

I have one option: I put task in queue 'create_client' with additional param such as

```
'create_task' => true
```

And then, in 'create_client' queue I will watch:

```
if ($params['create_task']) {
    Queue::put('create_task', $client_id)
}
```

I don't want do like this, but I don't have any idea how to do otherwise.

Help me please.
Thank you!